# Add line numb in apps script Console.error function

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, stackdriver

I'm using console.error() function to log errors for my sheets add-on made with apps script. E.g.:

```
 1   var a = null;
 2   a.toString();
 3   } catch(error) {
 4           console.error('Function_1(): ' + error); 
 5         }
```

However, my function is pretty big, and when I get some error like "`can't use toString() on null`", I'm not sure where the problem is.

I tried using it with throw:

```
1    var a = null;
2    a.toString();   
3    } catch(error) {
4           throw 'Function_1(): '+error; 
5          }
```

But then, I get the line number of throw:
`can't use toString() on null at line 4`, while the problem is at `line 2`.

I looked at other threads, like: 
[How do you pass back a custom error message from google apps scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180141/how-do-you-pass-back-a-custom-error-message-from-google-apps-scripts)

But well, it doesn't answer how to provide the correct line number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object, `error`, received by your `catch` block, you can observe that it has several properties that can be accessed:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (error) {
  const parts = {};
  for (var i in error) {
    parts[i] = error[i];
  }
  console.error({message: "Apps Script error object decomposition", error: error, parts: parts});
}
```

An example Stackdriver log:

[image]

So you can include the full stack trace of your error in your logs, as well as the file and line number:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (e) {
  console.error({
    message: "An error occurred",
    errMsg: e.message,
    line: e.lineNumber,
    fileName: e.fileName,
    stackTrace: e.stack
  });

  if (<some conditions>) {
    // update message:
    e.message = "Unhandled error in so-and-so: " + e.message;
    // Re-raise with the same trace info by re-throwing it:
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason e.lineNumber is null in Json Payload, but e.stack worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.lineNumber` where `e` is an Error object instance. Example:

```
function myFunction() {
  try {
    throw new Error('Error message');
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e.lineNumber)
  }
}
```

NOTE: Instead of `e` you could use `error` or any other variable name that fits your coding style.

Related

- [Appscript handled errors not shown in stackdriver errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54093641/1595451)

Comment: e.lineNumber is null in Json Payload. but it worked with e.stack, as @tehhowch suggested.

Comment: Have you tried the function on my answer? It works pretty fine for me. Anyway I added a Q/A related to the json payload "issue".